# Asp Core: Azure Ad Auth + custom JWT + custom Identity store

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

With ASP.NET Core 2.0 I try to achieve the following:

1. Authentication via Azure AD (registered App)
2. Custom JWT as the authentication scheme to

   - make the the web app auth work across servers/instances
   - be able to save the bearer to login with desktop clients
3. Have a custom identity store to introduce custom roles, policies, and other.

All these parts have working examples, but while trying to combine them I stumbled over some problems.

The Web Api + Azure Ad Auth example uses JWT Tokens for authentication, but doesn't have logic for validating or creating tokens. Neither does it have logic for login/logout, but this seems reasonable, its just Api.

Here is a quick reminder of the code of the Web Api example:

*AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
{
    public static class AzureAdServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
            => builder.AddAzureAdBearer(_ => { });

        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
            builder.AddJwtBearer();
            return builder;
        }

        private class ConfigureAzureOptions: IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
        {
            private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

            public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
            {
                _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
            }

            public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
            {
                options.Audience = _azureOptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
            }

            public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Excerpt of *Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

The Web Application + Azure Ad example on the other hand uses OpenId with cookies and does have login/logout logic:

*AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
{
    public static class AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
            => builder.AddAzureAd(_ => { });

        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
            return builder;
        }

        private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
        {
            private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

            public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
            {
                _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
            }

            public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            }

            public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Excerpt of *Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie();

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Account");
    });
}
```

*AccountController.cs*

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignIn()
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Page("/Index");
        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/SignedOut", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }
}
```

I have merged somehow both variants, but apparently it doesn't work. I replaced of course `CookieAuthenticationDefault` with `JwtBearerDefaults` in the login method.

Excerpt of *Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "localhost",
            ValidAudience = "localhost",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"))
        };
    });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Account");
    });
}
```

I don't fully understand how the different authentications are chained or depend on each other. I understand, that OpenId uses internally some sort of JWT, still the following questions remain:

- Why does the Web Api example just uses JWT, but the other uses OpenId with cookies ?
- Why does the OpenId example doesn't use JWT in the first place ?
- Does custom JWT work with OpenId ?
- Is it possible to introduce a custom identity store, but keep the Azure AD for login (and the login name) ?

It would be great if you could offer me some guidance, no fully working example needed (even though this would be great)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want combine Cookies and Bearer authorization in your ASP.NET Core web application, you could follow the code snippet below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions=> {
    jwtOptions.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    jwtOptions.Authority = "{Authority}";
    jwtOptions.Audience = "{Audience}";
    jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidIssuer = "{ValidIssuer}",
        ValidAudience = "{ValidAudience}"
    };
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
            //TODO:
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context => {
            //At this point, the security token has been validated successfully and a ClaimsIdentity has been created
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
            //add your custom claims here
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test", "helloworld!!!"));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
})
.AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
.AddCookie();
```

I noticed that you added a global `AuthorizeFilter`, at this time you need to make sure the anonymous action(s) need to decorate with `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
```

Or you could decorate the controller action with `Authorize` attribute as follows:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookies,Bearer")]
public IActionResult UserInfo()
{
    return Json(User.Claims.Select(c => new { key = c.Type, value = c.Value }));
}
```

For the OpenID Connect middleware, you could modify the `Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)` method under `AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs` file to add your custom claims (e.g. role,etc.) as follows:

```
public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    //the new code
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {   
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
            //add your custom claims here
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test", "helloworld!!!"));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
}
```

In summary, upon the configuration, you could combine Cookies and Bearer authentication, and after the token has been validated, you could retrieve the user identifier and get additional user info from your database, then attach them to `ClaimsIdentity`.

For desktop clients, you could leverage [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) (for AD app v1.0) or [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries) (for AD app v2.0) to log in and retrieve the `access_token` or `id_token`, then use it as the bearer token to access your web application.

Comment: But I still want to mention, that if you add the custom claims after OpenId validation and build your tokens based on these claims, you would add them a second time after JWTBearer validation. But you surely did this for a complete example.