# .NET 5.0 use JWT and OpenId Authorization

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a web API that I authorize against custom JWT like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
            var userId = new Guid(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
            var user = userService.GetById(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.Fail("Unauthorized");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
});
```

This all works fine. But now I also want to access the Microsoft Graph API in order to retrieve calendar data from a user.
So I figured I have to present the client with an OAuth dialogue, so I can retrieve the access token and make calls against the Microsoft Graph API.

I then registered an Microsoft application following the guide from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph

Now I have troubles to combine those two authentication schemes. I followed the answer from [Asp Core: Azure Ad Auth + custom JWT + custom Identity store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668735/asp-core-azure-ad-auth-custom-jwt-custom-identity-store)
And I added `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` over all my "old" controllers. This works until I add the new authentication scheme

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

like this

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
            var userId = new Guid(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
            var user = userService.GetById(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.Fail("Unauthorized");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I do not know how to incooperate the OpenId-part and the OAuth workflow is never called.

How can I integrate the additional Microsoft OAuth workflow from the github example on specific controllers without breaking my current authentication scheme? I know that the `AuthenticationSchemes`-name is missing, but I don't know, where to add it.

Did I choose the right OAuth workflow in the first place (user calls API, API triggers Microsoft OAuth to get token, API then uses token to fetch calendar data, API processes calendar data and then API passes the processed calendar data to user): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [A web app that calls web APIs: Code configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#option-1-call-microsoft-graph), it mentions the following information:

[image]

So far, what you have done seems to be right, and as per the documentation and the GitHub sample which you have provided, you have to add `GraphServiceClient` as one of the parameters in your target Controller and use it by assigning it's value to the controller's variable. The sample code of the controller will look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using _2_1_Call_MSGraph.Models;
using System.IO;

namespace _2_1_Call_MSGraph.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,
                          GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            ViewData["ApiResult"] = user.DisplayName;

            return View();
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
        {
            var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            ViewData["Me"] = me;

            try
            {
                // Get user photo
                using (var photoStream = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync())
                {
                    byte[] photoByte = ((MemoryStream)photoStream).ToArray();
                    ViewData["Photo"] = Convert.ToBase64String(photoByte);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                ViewData["Photo"] = null;
            }

            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the error message `{"Code: generalException\r\nMessage: An error occurred sending the request.\r\n"}`.

Comment: Pls check if you have put all the correct settings.